# Iterating over a nested list with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, smartsheet-api

I'm trying with my code to update smartsheet. I've got my data in a nested list and I want to pass it to the new_rows function each time (value by value).
I couldn't get it to iterate with regular methods as I've searched online because I think I missed something.
What happens now it just sends the first-row entry and then stops.
So i understand it needs to iterate over the nested list and do it in a loop but i couldn't figure out how to do that. Can anyone assist me?

```
import csv
import os
from simple_smartsheet import Smartsheet
from simple_smartsheet.models import Sheet, Column, Row, Cell, ColumnType
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Temp\Book1.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'TCU', 'Vendor', 'App', 'App_Version'])
example = df.values.tolist()
print(example)
TOKEN = os.getenv("")
SHEET_ID = "Book1"
smartsheet = Smartsheet("**************")

# retrieve a list of sheets (limited set of attributes)
sheet = smartsheet.sheets.get(SHEET_ID)
print(sheet)
new_rows = [
    Row(
        to_top=True,
        cells=[
            sheet.make_cell("Name", example[0][0]), 
            sheet.make_cell("TCU", example[0][0]),
            sheet.make_cell("Vendor", example[0][0]),
            sheet.make_cell("App",example[0][0]),
            sheet.make_cell("App_Version", example[0][0]),
        ],
    ),
]
smartsheet.sheets.add_rows(sheet.id, new_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only specifying the first element in your list, and never iterating over the remaining elements.

```
new_rows = []
for element in example:
    row = Row(to_top=True,
        cells=[
            sheet.make_cell("Name", element[0]),
            sheet.make_cell("TCU", element[1])
        ])
    new_rows.append(row)
```

Note that this example provides a couple different ways to access your list, and might need to be modified to fit the shape of whatever is contained inside `example`.